# ¿Es posible obtener una interfaz de una maquina virtual instalada en un servidor?

Tags: servidor, hosting, virtualización

Tengo un servidor en `Digital Ocean` con un `Ubuntu 18.04` , y si bien un 99% de las acciones que se realizan las puedo hacer por consola, existen un par que necesitaria poder obtener una vista de esa `maquina virtual.`

¿Existe algun metodo para poder acceder a ella?

Comment: Por favor lee [ask], edita y agrega lo que lleves

Comment: Hola, amigo te recomiendo que pases por aquí: [tour] y que te leas estos artículos: [help/dont-ask], [help/on-topic], [help/behavior] y que arregles tu pregunta mirando este articulo: [mcve] tambien puedes pedir ayuda en: [chat]

Comment: tu problema esta relacionada al manejo de aplicaciones en el sistema operativo, y no a algo relacionado a los objetivos del sitio (Desarrollo y programación).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si es ubuntu server usa `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` y `sudo apt-get install xorg gnome-core` para instalar la interface grafica y al finalizar teclea en la terminal `startx` y si tienes ubuntu desktop no necesitas instalar entorno grafico solo teclea `startx`

Comment: Una maquina virtual no es mas que un hipervisor que hace que tu hadware ejemplo disco duro y ram se puedan virtualizar para darle una parte de sus recursos a sistemas operativos virtuales, es como una computadora dentro de otra así que practicamente se puede hacer todo lo de una pc normal

Answer (score 1):

Lo que necesitas es iniciar una sesión gráfica remota.
Doy por hecho que el servidor se encuentra en una ubicación diferente a donde tu te encuentras (no importa si es una virtual, la maquina virtual pudiera estar montada sobre un servidor físico remoto). Para hacer esto:

1. El entorno X del servidor esta levantado (como indica el compañero @Erik Perez)
2. Debes asegurarte que en el archivo **/etc/ssh/ssh_config** del servidor tengas el siguiente valor:

   ForwardX11 yes

3.1. Debes iniciar una sesión ssh hacia tu servido como sigue (la opción -X indicará que vas a trabajar con el entorno gráfico)

```
ssh -X tusuaurio@ipTuservidor
```

Luego ya conectado ejecutas:

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

Nota: Hay quien pone:

```
export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0
```

Y quien pone (esta última es la que suelo usar yo).

```
export DISPLAY=tuIp:0.0
```

Luego desde la terminal invoca al comando gráfico que necesites.

Por ejemplo con lo mencionado anteriormente al conectarme desde un Windows XP a un Fedora 31 puedo invocar al programa Kolourpaint y ver el programa en ejecución como si fuera un programa de Windows:

[image: Ejecutando kolourpaint desde windows]

3.2. Puedes usar el programa [MobaXterm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/download.html) con el no es necesario ejecutar el export DISPLAY.